# Serialize dictionary containing custom object which includes two dictionaries

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

In my program, I save some data in a custom object:

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(MsgTimerSettings))]
    public class MsgTimerSettings
    {
        public string t_name { get; set; }
        public string t_subj { get; set; }
        public string t_nmsg { get; set; }
        public UUID t_attach { get; set; }
        public string t_attachName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, UUID> t_ngroups { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, UUID> t_imgroups { get; set; }
        public string t_IMmsg { get; set; }
        public string t_SLURL { get; set; }
        public int t_Type { get; set; }
        public int t_IMsetting { get; set; }
        public int t_ImgIndex { get; set; }
        public bool t_StartNow { get; set; }
        public DateTime t_StartTime { get; set; }
        public bool t_EndAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime t_EndTime { get; set; }
        public int t_Number { get; set; }
        public string t_Period { get; set; }
        public int t_Interval { get; set; }
        public bool t_Active { get; set; }
    }
```

Each of these objects are then stored in a Dictionary(Dictionary MsgTimers;)
The dictionary key is the name of the timer.

Now, what I would like to do is to save each of these objects into an XML file so that I can read the timers back next time I start the program.

I know that dictionaries isn't serializable and I have tried to find different solutions to work around the problem, but to no avail.

I have tried to use the SerializableDictionary workaround presented at: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx in order to make serializable dictionaries, but others than just making my dictionaries into SerializableDictionaries, I still have no clue...

The code I have tried to serialize with, is the following:

```
    static public void SerializeToXML(SerializableDictionary<string, object> ST)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string,object>));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ST.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, ST);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

Hope anyone could help me out.

Comment: Why SerializableDictionary<string, object> instead of SerializableDictionary<string, MsgTimerSettings>? You have to "help" the XmlSerializer to do its job.

Comment: Thank you Adriano, that's exactly what was needed. Wish I could mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: you can't mark a comment as solution; it was pretty short to be a true answer, glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To serialize/deserialize Dictionary without introducing a serializable dictionary, I use this class:

```
public class DictionarySerializer : IXmlSerializable
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary;

    private DictionarySerializer()
    {
        this._dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    }

    private DictionarySerializer(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        this._dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public static void Serialize(StreamWriter stream, Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        DictionarySerializer ds = new DictionarySerializer(dictionary);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        xs.Serialize(stream, ds);
    }

    public static void Serialize(Stream stream, Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        DictionarySerializer ds = new DictionarySerializer(dictionary);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        xs.Serialize(stream, ds);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        DictionarySerializer ds = (DictionarySerializer)xs.Deserialize(stream);
        return ds._dictionary;
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Deserialize(TextReader stream)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        DictionarySerializer ds = (DictionarySerializer)xs.Deserialize(stream);
        return ds._dictionary;
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.Read();
        ReadFromXml(reader);
    }

    private void ReadFromXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement("dictionary");
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");
            string key = reader.ReadElementString("key");
            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            object value = null;
            if (reader.Name == string.Empty)
            {
                value = reader.Value;
                reader.Read();
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "dictionary")
            {
                DictionarySerializer innerSerializer = new DictionarySerializer();
                innerSerializer.ReadFromXml(reader);
                value = innerSerializer._dictionary;
            }
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
            _dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }


    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("dictionary");
        foreach (string key in _dictionary.Keys)
        {
            object value = _dictionary[key];
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
            writer.WriteElementString("key", key.ToString());
            if (value is Dictionary<string, object>)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("value");
                IXmlSerializable aSer = new DictionarySerializer((Dictionary<string, object>)value);
                aSer.WriteXml(writer);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            else
                writer.WriteElementString("value", value.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Then I use this kind of code to serialize/deserialize the dictionary:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        // fill the dictionary
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pth);
        DictionarySerializer.Serialize(sw, d);
        sw.Close();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pth);
        Dictionary<string, object> d2 = DictionarySerializer.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Close();
```